# ksmooth function in R

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

I'm trying to understand how `ksmooth` function in R works.

I was hoping to use `ksmooth` to pick out "significant" differences. For example, with the below example, since `cars_high` (or green line) is for a "baseline" of the general trend, and `cars_low` (or red line) follows the data points more closely, so that `cars_high[[2]]-cars_low[[2]]` will indicate how much each distance diverges away from the general trend.

```
cars[,1] <- sort(runif(50, 4, 25))
with(cars, {
  plot(speed, dist)
  lines(ksmooth(speed, dist, "normal", bandwidth = 0.5), col = 2)
  lines(ksmooth(speed, dist, "normal", bandwidth = 5), col = 3)
})
cars_low <- ksmooth(cars[,1], cars[,2], "normal", bandwidth=0.5, n.points = 50)
cars_high <- ksmooth(cars[,1], cars[,2], "normal", bandwidth=5, n.points = 50)
```

Eventually I want to set up a threshold, like below (`high`), and extract distances from the original dataset.

```
high <- which((cars_high[[2]]-cars_low[[2]])>10
cars[,2][high]
```

The problem with this idea is that by using `ksmooth` I'm also changing `speed` of `cars`. So if there's a large difference bewteen `cars_high[[1]]` and `cars[,1]`, the distance values I'm getting from `cars[high,2]` can be really off.

This made me wonder if it was possible to manipulate `ksmooth` so that the x values (`speed`) won't change by smoothing and only y values (`dist`) change. Maybe fixing x values just doesn't make any sense mathematically? Or should this be done using a different function than `ksmooth`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. The phrasing '(hoping to use ksmooth to pick out "significant" differences*' really doesn't convey anything to me (and I suspect you're not saying what you intend). Without using any statistical jargon at all -- just the plainest of ordinary English (like you're telling a smart 12 year old, say), could you outline what you want achieve?

Comment: @Glen_b My data is a list of x and y values, and if I plot them, I get a very noisy plot with lots of zigzags. I'm trying to figure out which of those oscillations are large enough to survive a basic filtering (which is what I'm using `ksmooth` for). So I'm first drawing a very rough outline (with small `bandwidth`), then drawing another outline that follows the real dataset more closely but not too close to replicate all the noise (with large `bandwidth`), then subtracting the former from the latter to only sort out zigzags that were large enough to survive that filtering process.